# Sum of strings (UTF-16 codepoints)

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

Your function must accept two [strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/8964#8964) and return new string where are UTF-16 code of all symbols is the sum of UTF-16 codes of inputs symbols

- If the resulting sum is greater than `65535` (maximum UTF-16 codepoint), take the sum modulo `65536`
- If there are more symbols in one string then sum with zero, codes of symbols which doesn't have pairs

For example:

- `'a' + 'b' = a(97) + b(98) = 97 + 98 = 195 => 'Ã'`
- `'A' + 'B' = A(65) + B(66) = 65 + 66 = 131 => '\u0083' (No Break Here)`
- `'Aa' + 'BbC' = [A(65) + B(66)][a(97) + b(98)][(0) + C(67)] => '\u0083ÃC'` - `\u0083` will not be displayed but it must be here so the length of result string must be 3 not 2

**Test cases**:

```
'a', 'b' --> 'Ã'

'A', 'B' --> '\u0083'

'Aa', 'BbC' --> '\u0083ÃC'

'耀', '耀' --> '\u0000' (Null character)

'Программирование', 'Programming' --> 'ѯҲҭҚҲґҩҩҡҮҥвание'
```

Ungolfed version (check in real time):

```js
const updateResult = () => {
  const string_1 = input1.value;
  const string_2 = input2.value;
  resultString = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < string_1.length || i < string_2.length; ++i) {
    resultString.push(
      (string_1.charCodeAt(i) || 0) +
      (string_2.charCodeAt(i) || 0)
    );
  }
  
  resultString = String.fromCharCode(...resultString);
  
  result.innerHTML = resultString;
  resultLength.innerHTML = 'Length: ' + resultString.length;
}

input1.addEventListener('input', updateResult);
input2.addEventListener('input', updateResult);

updateResult();
```

```html
<input id="input1" value="aA"/>
<input id="input2" value="bB"/>

<br/><br/>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultLength"></div>
```

The shortest code in each programming language wins!

Comment: How does the last test case have `\u0083` between the other two instead of being first?

Comment: @12944qwerty You are completely right, thank you!

Comment: Is outputting an array of 1 element each valid or must it be a string?

Comment: @12944qwerty Array of chars also a string. Please check the link given in challenge to see what is string in codegolf challenges

Comment: Suggested tag: [string](/questions/tagged/string)

Comment: @TheThonnu Added. Thank you!

Comment: Are the characters guaranteed to be in Unicode Plane 0?

Comment: @alephalpha All symbols will be from range `[\u+0000, \u+ffff]`

Comment: Note that the output might not be a valid unicode string, as you might get unpaired surrogates.

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```
=CONCAT(
    TOCOL(UNICHAR(MOD(MMULT(IFERROR(UNICODE(MID(A1:B1,ROW(A:A),1)),),{1;1}),4^8)),2)
)
```

Inputs in cells `A1` and `B1`.

*Thanks to JvdV for the 3-byte save*.

Comment: 89 Bytes `=CONCAT(TOCOL(UNICHAR(MOD(MMULT(IFERROR(UNICODE(MID(A1:B1,ROW(A:A),1)),),{1,1}),4^8)),2))`

Comment: @JvdV :-) That's sneaky! `TOCOL` with 2nd parameter can replace `IFERROR`!

Comment: Would just change your `{1,1}` to `{1;1}` for English-language versions maybe.

Comment: Woops, yes, that's a typo!

Comment: And thanks very much for taking the time to look at and improve upon my posts here. Much appreciated. On a pure byte count it's obviously near impossible to compete with the vast majority of the other languages here, but at least we can keep the Excel flag flying, for what it's worth.

Comment: No problem, it's very interesting browsing through them and looking at the techniques applied.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
C∑k₴%C
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJD4oiRa+KCtCVDIiwiIiwiW1wi0J/RgNC+0LPRgNCw0LzQvNC40YDQvtCy0LDQvdC40LVcIiwgXCJQcm9ncmFtbWluZ1wiXSJd)

**How it works**:

```
C∑k₴%C
C∑       Sum codepoints of each word
  k₴%    Push 65535 and modulo by each element
     C   Convert codepoints to words
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of 2 character arrays, outputs a single character array.

```
ÕËxc uG²² d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=bXE&code=1ct4YyB1R7KyIGQ&footer=VnE&input=WwoiXHU4MDAwIgoiXHU4MDAwIgpdCi1R)

```
ÕËxc uG²² d     :Implicit input of 2D array
Õ               :Transpose
 Ë              :Map
  x             :  Sum of
   c            :    Codepoints
     u          :  Modulo
      G         :    16
       ²²       :    Squared twice
          d     :  Character at resulting codepoint
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 89 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[chr(sum(map(ord,a))%4**8)for a in zip(f'{x:\0<{len(y)}}',f'{y:\0<{len(x)}}')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYxNDgFBEIX3TtEb6WrpiISFCAtcwB6L9jOjRf@kjGSGSOYmriBEYoEztFu4xei2sCaVVL33Ut@zWbIwut60WESdUbESajITJOVZazhdIKw3CpSwYHDGBWPlRqXSZJFBIojUZCstRHSXtka19m4115Cx/Z5yH2XfKA0RGxdCr0mHREC7gnJCe5M@ZSWLUieAc4tAaXVppAb/xxgnAf3I0hd0h2fuHu7s99Hd/Fw//uTd3V3dJdQO0MQolJI6/rf@leehIZyfyOIN)

-15 bytes thanks to @SevC_10

Comment: Here are some improvements: 1. no need for the external `map`; 2. use the f-string for padding the strings to equal length; 3. use `\0` for the `NUL` character. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##lYxNDgFBEIX3TtEb6WrpiISFCAtcwB6L9jOjRf@kjGSGSOYmriBEYoEztFu4xei2sCaVVL33Ut@zWbIwut60WESdUbESajITJOVZazhdIKw3CpSwYHDGBWPlRqXSZJFBIojUZCstRHSXtka19m4115Cx/Z5yH2XfKA0RGxdCr0mHREC7gnJCe5M@ZSWLUieAc4tAaXVppAb/xxgnAf3I0hd0h2fuHu7s99Hd/Fw//uTd3V3dJdQO0MQolJI6/rf@leehIZyfyOIN) 89 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0ζOžH%ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4Nw2/6P7PFQPL///P1r9wvyLDRf2XdgMJDdc2AOEO8D8TUDe3gs7LmxV11FQDyjKTy9KzM3NzEtXjwUA)

##### Explanation

```python
0ζOžH%ç  # 05AB1E automatically converts the strings
         # to codepoints since they are delimited by '
0ζ       # Transpose with filler 0
  O      # Sum each inner list
   žH    # Push 65536 
     %   # Mod each value by 65536
      ç  # Convert back from codepoint to character
```

Comment: "_05AB1E automatically converts the strings to codepoints since they are in a list_" Didn't even knew it did this. o.Ô Nice answer!

Comment: I think the reason this works is that items and lists are evaluated by elixir, and `'`-delimited strings are codepoint lists in Elixir. This is different if you use `"` as string delimiters

Comment: @ovs oh yeah, you're right. I didn't check that.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>30</s> <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
(65536|+/@,:)&.(3 u:7&u:)
```

-3 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), and -2 more.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxU8PM1NTYrEZb30HHSlNNT8NYodTKXK3UShMif7NGkys1OSNfQT1RXSFNQT1JHcp1BHOd4FyItFNSMkzkRUMDWAhEQ4UuzL_YcGHfhc1AcsOFPUC4A8zfBOTtvbDjwlaw-oCi_PSixNzczLx0dYgbFiyA0AA)

```
(65536|+/@,:)&.(3 u:7&u:)
             &.            NB. u&.v applies v to both args and u to the results
                           NB. then applies the inverse of v to the results of u
               (3 u:7&u:)  NB. monadic fork
                    7&u:   NB. converts each char to a single unicode codepoint
                3 u:       NB. convert string to a list of codepoints
(65536|+/@,:)              NB. dyadic fork
          ,:               NB. stacks codepoint lists filling with 0s
       +/@                 NB. then sum the columns of the resulting table
 65536|                    NB. mod each sum by 65536
                           NB. inverse of v converts codepoints to chars
```

Comment: I don't think the `!.0` is necessary, that seems to be the default behaviour.

Comment: Good catch, I was so focused on trying to get `,.` to work...

Comment: `(65536|[+/@,:])&.(3 u:7&u:)` alternate 27

Comment: Pretty sure you drop `[` and `]`?

Comment: Huh, yeah. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

## Z80 machine language, 52 bytes

Null-terminated strings, addresses passed in `DE` and `HL`;
output string address passed in `BC`.
Little-endian.

```
D5 E5 7E 23 B6 23 EB 28 0A 7E 23 B6 23 EB 20 F4
37 E1 D5 30 03 EB C5 7E 02 23 03 B6 7E 02 23 03
20 F7 E1 1A 47 86 77 13 23 1A 4F 8E 77 13 23 78
B1 20 F2 C9
```

Disassembled:

```
f:
    push de         // D5
    push hl         // E5
wl:
    ld a,(hl)       // 7E       // test one wchar of each
    inc hl          // 23
    or (hl)         // B6
    inc hl          // 23
    ex de,hl        // EB
    jr z,fzero      // 28 0A
    ld a,(hl)       // 7E
    inc hl          // 23
    or (hl)         // B6
    inc hl          // 23
    ex de,hl        // EB
    jr nz,wl        // 20 F4
    scf             // 37       // if we have made it here, first was shorter
fzero:
    pop hl          // E1
    pop de          // D5
    jr nc,copy      // 30 03
    ex de,hl        // EB
copy:               //          when we get here, wstrlen(hl)>wstrlen(de)
    push bc         // C5
cl:
    ld a,(hl)       // 7E       // copy a byte
    ld (bc),a       // 02
    inc hl          // 23
    inc bc          // 03
    or (hl)         // B6       // or in the second to see if both 0
    ld a,(hl)       // 7E       // copy the second (preserves flags)
    ld (bc),a       // 02
    inc hl          // 23
    inc bc          // 03
    jr nz,cl        // 20 F7    // if either nonzero, loop again
    pop hl          // E1       // put dest in hl
aloop:
    ld a,(de)       // 1A
    ld b,a          // 47
    add (hl)        // 86
    ld (hl),a       // 77
    inc de          // 13       // *(hl++) += (b = *(de++)
    inc hl          // 23
    ld a,(de)       // 1A
    ld c,a          // 4F
    adc (hl)        // 8E
    ld (hl),a       // 77
    inc de          // 13
    inc hl          // 23       // *(hl++) += (c = *(de++)) + cf
    ld a,b          // 78
    or c            // B1
    jr nz,aloop     // 20 F2    // continue if b|c
    ret             // C9
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a and b and chr(ord(a[0])+ord(b[0])&65535)+f(a[1:],b[1:])or a+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDNSsNAEL7nKYYc3KxNS6RUpFClLS0IooV6qznsNps2sPlhm6i9FfoEXr2IBw8e/KEi9KBe@gJpnsK3iLttsToD387MN9@3y0bjeBgG5Tx3a5z41CFATFqVGDhAV9gfCiMUjkF6lo0LqqKq2tmvVMoVXHAlsVe1TaoQhwJIgeaeH4UiBsE0LRbjqgYyroYeZ3AuErbuVRATqAkMauCTyGCXhJtSVHK9wCGcGzoq7R4h3QQviJLYwBj/KkOpkVdL/XYWCS@IDb3XqXe7tg6eq7Zq0p7xEQO9164fn9jSLcQau@6zKIbWWbslRCjWL4rIaKTliCATEEVQLB4CWkyRhupq0thMLhLLOiir6WqxQZv/iMW0KbnvyUSR6tiSloXAOE04l39KBOnHTGANpXfLSfqVvkl8TT9kzlf9THaf6Tx9Vz4dEQ4E8X0vGGz8li/ZLHvKbiXeZI8y77Pn7OGP6gc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 61 bytes

```
{utf16(roundrobin(@_».encode('utf16'))».sum X%4⁸).decode}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urQkzdBMLy@1XKMovzQvpSg/KTNPwyH@0G691Lzk/JRUDXWwCnVNTaBQcWmuQoSqyaPGHZp6Kakg6dr/xYmVCnpZ@UBd6joK6ppArGBrpwBkp2nUqMRrKqTlFynYJCok2eko2DgqOIGpRAWnJGcQ60VDgwIQg5gX5l9suLDvwmYgueHCHiDcAeZvAvL2XthxYatCQFF@elFibm5mXrrdfwA)

(The older Raku version on TIO requires a ".new" after the first "utf16" for four additional bytes.)

- `@_` are the string arguments to the function.
- `».encode('utf16')` encodes each of those strings as a utf16 blob object.
- `roundrobin` combines corresponding elements of those blobs as lists, like `zip`, but doesn't stop when the end of the shortest input is reached.  `roundrobin <1 2>, <3 4 5 6>` returns `(1 3), (2, 4), (5,), (6,)`.
- `».sum` converts each of those zipped lists to its sum.
- `X% 4⁸` takes each of those sums modulo 65536.  (`4⁸` is one byte shorter than `65536`.)
- `utf16` converts that list of integers to a utf16 blob.
- `.decode` converts that blob into a string.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 91 bytes ([tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)'s [method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258550/sum-of-strings-utf-16-codepoints/258551?noredirect=1#comment570818_258551))

With recursion

```
(a,b)=>(g=i=>a[i]?String.fromCharCode(a[c='charCodeAt'](i)+~~b[c](i))+g(i+1):b.slice(i))(0)
```

Try it:

```js
f=(a,b)=>(g=i=>a[i]?String.fromCharCode(a[c='charCodeAt'](i)+~~b[c](i))+g(i+1):b.slice(i))(0)

const inputHandler = () => {  
  resultString = f(input1.value, input2.value)
  
  result.innerHTML = resultString;
  resultLength.innerHTML = 'Length: ' + resultString.length;
}

input1.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
input2.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);

inputHandler();
```

```html
<input id="input1" value="aA"/>
<input id="input2" value="bB"/>

<br/><br/>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultLength"></div>
```

## JavaScript, 97 bytes

Without recursion

```
(a,b)=>String.fromCharCode(...[...a].map((s,i)=>(g=c=>c.charCodeAt(j=i)|0)(a)+g(b)))+b.slice(j+1)
```

Try it:

```js
f=(a,b)=>String.fromCharCode(...[...a].map((s,i)=>(g=c=>c.charCodeAt(j=i)|0)(a)+g(b)))+b.slice(j+1)

const inputHandler = () => {  
  resultString = f(input1.value, input2.value)
  
  result.innerHTML = resultString;
  resultLength.innerHTML = 'Length: ' + resultString.length;
}

input1.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
input2.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);

inputHandler();
```

```html
<input id="input1" value="aA"/>
<input id="input2" value="bB"/>

<br/><br/>

<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultLength"></div>
```

Comment: `a=>b=>(g=i=>a[i]?String.fromCharCode(a[c='charCodeAt'](i)+~~b[c](i))+g(i+1):b.slice(i))(0)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 38 bytes

```factor
[ 0 pad-longest [ + 65536 mod ] 2map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQWFycn1ysUJxaWJqal5yKxNJLrSgpSixWyE0syVAoKEotKaksKMrMK1Gw5qrmUgCCagWlRCUFpSQlhVoY3xHId0LmgxQ4JTkjCb1oaFCCknCxC/MvNlzYd2EzkNxwYQ8Q7gDzNwF5ey/suLAVqCGgKD@9KDE3NzMvHaSx9n@0goFCQWKKbk5@XnpqcYlCtIK2gpmpqbGZQm5@ikKsglFuYoFC7P80iA/tQLziksTkbL3/AA)

- `0 pad-longest` pad the shorter of two sequences with 0s until it is the same length as the longer one
- `[ ... ] 2map` map over two sequences with a binary function
- `+ 65536 mod` add the code points together modulo 65536

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＳＵＭυ⁺ι×ψ⁻Ｌ§υ¬ιＬι⭆⊟υ℅﹪⁺℅ι℅§ΣυκＸ⁴¦⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5LasMwEN3nFFqOQN2ELgpZlawCdStILyBsxxaVNEaW2maXm@QKISWQRdIzqCdSx2rDwDBvZt6n7pWvUZmcN@gZzDmTcewhCrZyQwzr4LXrgPPFrFLDEq1Vrpmu0sQRtGCv2rYjbAWrtKPNU@u60MNjWLmm/ZwenzGA5pwL9n@bAMlJEg7wp0/SIHGASF9LCqTq0HqosIkGoTi9@EY7ZYgs2G2@mayjLcy34iLxg7j3gj3wYpRz2v/s0nf6on5IF6pzwUdC13ROJ4qCnVfWUpJ8925@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＳ
```

Input the two strings.

```
ＵＭυ⁺ι×ψ⁻Ｌ§υ¬ιＬι
```

Pad the shorter to the length of the longer with null bytes.

```
⭆⊟υ℅﹪⁺℅ι℅§ΣυκＸ⁴¦⁸
```

Pairwise add the character codes of the two strings, reduce module `4⁸`, then convert back to characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
ạᵐz₁+ᵐ%₆₅₅₃₆ᵐ~ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhQ@3Tqh61NSoDaRVHzW1PWpqBaNmIBsoVAdU8f9/tNKF@RcbLuy7sBlIbriwBwh3gPmbgLy9F3Zc2Kqko6AUUJSfXpSYm5uZl64U@z8KAA)

#### Explanation

```
ạᵐ               Map to codes
  z₁             Zip without cycling
    +ᵐ           Map sum
      %₆₅₅₃₆ᵐ    Map mod 65536
             ~ạ  Codes to string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-fwide-exec-charset=UTF16LE`, 78 bytes

Takes inputs in UCS-2 (UTF-16LE) encoding and outputs in UCS-2 (UTF-16LE) encoding. TIO and shells don't seem to like UTF-16: running this from an actual machine and redirecting the output gives the correct results.

Output (in KWrite, UTF-16 encoding):

[image: UTF-16 output]

```c
f(i,j,k)short*i,*j;{for(;*i|*j;*i&&i++,*j&&j++)printf("%2$c%c",k>>8,k=*i+*j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9PSsNAGMX3PcUQbDr/Am0XIgwpWNFVFy50pS7SaSadxCQyGVSogdzEK4hS6EI9w3gLT2GcjKEy8Ob7ve97i8eDhPO2FVDSlGaoWpdKY0lxyjaiVJBh@WRnLH1fEmJt308JQXdKFlpAbzg94EPu0Ww2O6JZiCXBKWJ1a7cgj2QB70u5QmAzAKCzcHV1E3YAwMKLPGp16dGejx3P//nvYL482VvfTeM89/eeef5qzKd5s/pi3u3bOX619GF2ZusC56pMVJTnskj64NhqTQHGmg3s2HXVYcWAZaBJOKVg39E1HF0XIzpGCAiItc1BTSYIsUHd/nBxGyVVG4gHuYqD@DHmAV9Hqop1eHlxNjlcnP4C)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
z::i::+:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/b/KyirTykrbKvl/rVWodbTShfkXGy7su7AZSG64sAcId4D5m4C8vRd2XNiqpKAUUJSfXpSYm5uZl64UG/ofAA)

## Explanation

```
z::i::+:c # a function taking an array with two strings [x y]
z         # zip; transpose rows with columns (i.e, ["Aa" "BbC"] => ["AB" "ab" "C"]
 ::i      # map `i`nt convert to all values
    ::+   # map add to all values, effectively summing each
       :c # map each summed value to `c`hars
```